# Understanding QGIS scale dependent visibilty?

Tags: qgis

I cannot understand why the scale dependent visibility function does not want to work in QGIS.

I'm using the latest version (2.8.1 Wien) and want to insert diagrams (pie/histogram) to illustrate different statistical data.

It is a very simple and easy task to do, but for some reason the diagrams does not adhere to the minimum and maximum scale parameters I've entered.

Is there any assistance out there? Am I entering incorrect numbers? Is this scale based function different than rendering labels? What is it I am not understanding?

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug (https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10700) with scale dependent visibility of diagrams.

Recently it was fixed and (as I tested on QGIS 2.8.2) I can confirm the issue is gone.

Update your QGIS to the most recent version and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. It is highly appreciated.